# Cross domain calls, REST library

Tags: javascript, api, rest, cross-domain

I'm trying to use an external REST Library for my application, and I'm hoping to keep it client side, with javascript.
I have no control over the REST library servers, so I cannot modify any access rights or anything on the servers. (It's kept secure by OAuth).

My question is: Is it possible to connect with the REST API using only javascript?
I'm bound to running into cross domain call problems.
Using JSONP is not possible from what I gather, since I would only be able to do GET's and not POST's, right? Also, I don't know a lot about JSONP...does it perhaps require me to make some changes on the API-offering server too?(in which case I can't).

Is there a way to workaround this problem, or will I be forced to do some serverside programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for modern browsers. Then there are a couple of other hacks, described very well here: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Otherwise you'll have to do the server side programming.

Comment: About CORS, for that to work, the REST API server must support CORS by setting the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" things, right?

Comment: Yes absolutely. So that'd probably result in some server side programming also :P